# Aggregation does not work properly in sql, in a many to many relationship, because of where clause

Tags: sql, mysql, join, where-clause, aggregate-functions

## My setup

I have two tables, watch, and tags. They are in a many to many relationship joined by a table called linked_watch_tags. I have a query, where I JOIN these tables, GROUP the query by the watch.id, and then GROUP_CONCAT, all the related tags, into a column called tags

### old query that works

```sql
SELECT id, display_name, price, tags FROM (
    SELECT 
        watch.id AS id, display_name, price, discount, in_stock_amount, dial_size,
        image_path, qualities, added_on, GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name) AS tags
    FROM watch
        LEFT JOIN linked_watch_tag ON watch_id = watch.id
        LEFT JOIN tag ON tag_id = tag.id
    GROUP BY watch.id
) as TEMP
```

## The problem

I want to query all the watches that have a certain tag with `WHERE tag.name = 'Analogue'`, but doing that ruins `GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name)`

### new query that fails

```sql
SELECT id, display_name, price, tags FROM (
    SELECT 
        watch.id AS id, display_name, price, discount, in_stock_amount, dial_size,
        image_path, qualities, added_on, GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name) AS tags
    FROM watch
        LEFT JOIN linked_watch_tag ON watch_id = watch.id
        LEFT JOIN tag ON tag_id = tag.id
    WHERE tag.name = 'Analogue' -- This is causing the problem
    GROUP BY watch.id
) as TEMP
```

### previous output

```
tags: "Analogue,Mens,Red"
```

### New output

```
tags: "Analogue"
```

as you can see it does not include the other tags

Comment: You must investigate not separate tag (this will eliminate all another tags) but the list of tags for needed tag presence. So not `WHERE tag.name = 'Analogue'` but `HAVING MAX(tag.name = 'Analogue')` or `HAVING FIND_IN_SET('Analogue', tags)`.

Comment: *new query that fails* !!! not "fails" but "does not produce required output".

Comment: The problem is in the SELECT of the subquery. You only are allowed to SELECT the columns that are present in the GROUP BY (tag.name) or an aggregation.

Comment: @LucasDavidFerrero `tag.name` is in an aggregate function and all the others are [functionally dependent](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) on `watch.id` (PK), so they are fine.